# undefined local variable or method `oauth_token' when sending Tweets from Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm currently working on sharpening my RoR skills after spending three months learning the basics through a bootcamp. I'm slowly building concept upon concept with an app I'm working on to create a Twitter utility (been done, I know. It's been good practice).

After much trepidation I was able to get oauth-twitter up and running but now I'm starting to scratch the surface of the Twitter API and I'm having some difficulties.

I've created what I believe is all the functionality to send tweets directly from my application but, upon hitting send I get this error:

```
NameError at /tweets
undefined local variable or method 'oauth_token' for #<User:0x007f821a6b66d0>`
```

It's throwing it off this block of code:

```
def tweet(tweet)
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = Rails.application.config.twitter_key
      config.consumer_secret = Rails.application.config.twitter_secret
      config.access_token = oauth_token
      config.access_token_secret = oauth_secret
    end
    client.update(tweet)
  end
end
```

With the error being highlighted at `config.access_token = oauth_token`

The server stack trace gives me this:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `consumer_key' for #    <Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f82182b9188>:
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in     `method_missing'
  app/models/user.rb:16:in `block in tweet'
  twitter (5.15.0) lib/twitter/client.rb:23:in `initialize'
  app/models/user.rb:15:in `tweet'
```

If anyone could take a look at this and give me some feedback I'd much appreciate it. You can check out the branch in my repo where this is all stored here: [InsomniaNoir - Project: :kronoTweeter](https://github.com/InsomniaNoir/kronoTweeter/tree/sendtweets)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have not both `oauth_token` and `oauth_secret` in `users` table. You need create new migration like this:

```
rails g migration AddOauthFieldsToUsers oauth_token oauth_secret
```

after this don't forget run

```
rake db:migrate
```

then should be modified `from_omniauth` method in `User` class

```
def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
  user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
  user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
  user.location = auth_hash['info']['location']
  user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
  user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls']['Twitter']
  user.oauth_token=auth_hash.credentials.token
  user.oauth_secret=auth_hash.credentials.secret
  user.save!
  user
end
```

Comment: This allowed me to get past the original issue but now it throws this error:

`Twitter::Error::Forbidden at /tweets
Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.`

I'm using Figaro so my credentials are all stored in `application.yml`

Comment: I think you are not setting environment vars correctly. Just for test purpose, try manually input your data instead of `Rails.application.config.twitter_key` and `Rails.application.config.twitter_secret` in `tweet` method.